# Dependent project complexity

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Initially I was developing window(Form) project 1 named Proj1. I added another project 2 named Proj2 to Proj1. Added references of Proj2 in Proj1. Made Proj2 as a startup project. While compiling and running, everything is fine. Built it rebuilt it in both release mode and debug mode. Now I copied the exe of Proj1 and put it at different place. It runs without showing any dependency error but starting point is Proj1 not Proj2.

To resolve it I opened solution file of Proj2 and added Proj1 there and added references also. Put Proj2 as starting file. It is Running well. But when I copy exe of Proj2 to some another place, It shows dependency error. When I put Proj1 exe at that place, it runs well.

The Error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'MyExcelReader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at CodeGen.Program.CreateNominals(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlNode rootNode)
   at CodeGen.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding references to projects alone does not cause this exception - it occurs when the code is trying to load a certain type from another assembly.

So apparently `Proj2` is trying to load a type from `Proj1`, and since you didn't copy the `Proj1` assembly to the directory in which you are running it, it cannot load that type.

Perhaps you could share what you are trying to achieve, and why you expected `Proj2` to run without `Proj1`?

Comment: Thank you @C.Evenhuis. I Just added the exe of Proj1 to the directory of Proj2. It run.